# Deserialize bitmap image and compare it with images in resources

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a BindingList used by a datagridview.  One of the columns in my datagridview displays one of 3 images representing success, failure, or unknown.  These images are specified from my resources.

I'm able to successfully serialize/deserialize the bitmaps using a memory stream. However, once deserialized back into a bitmap, I can't determine which of the 3 images it is.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  Essentially I want to know:

```
if(deserializedImage == resources.successImage)
```

Another approach I'd be happy to take: Technically I don't need to serialize the image, I just need to serialize some kind of reference that tells it which resource to use. The trick would be making it deserialize into a bitmap that I could compare with my resource files.

This is my binding list:

```
public BindingList<Iam> DatagridList { get; set; }
```

And this is a greatly simplified version of my Iam object (I've removed my memorystream code):

```
public class Iam
{
   public string AssemblyPath { get; set; }
   public Bitmap UpToDate { get; set; }
}
```

In summary, how can I serialize a bitmap, but deserialize it in a way where I can compare it with images in my resources to determine which was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just storing a string to signify which image to display.  The Bitmap property just references which string to use.  I never serialize the bitmap.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Bitmap UpToDate
{
    get
    {
        //Only null if file entered is invalid. This causes image to be blank
        if (UpToDateString == null) 
            return null;

        //Translates from the resource specified to the bitmap object being used
        var resourceObject = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(UpToDateString);
        return (Bitmap) resourceObject;
    }
}

//This holds the reference for which resource image to use
[XmlElement("UpToDate")]
public string UpToDateString { get; set; }
```